# Finding the symbolic inverse of a function

Tags: function-construction, special-functions, inverse

Is there a way of inverting this function to obtain $r(\rho)$?

```
rho[r_, b0_, q_] := 
  r (1 + (Sqrt[π]Gamma[1/(q - 1)])/((1 - q) Gamma[1/2 ((q + 1)/(q - 1))]) b0 /r + (1 + q)/(2 q) (b0/r)^(1 - q))
```

Note that $q<0$ and $b0$ is some positive constant.

Answer (score 2):

The typical way to do this, is to use `Solve` or `Reduce` get `r` to one side of the equality. It seems like Mathematica cannot solve the equation, unfortunately:

```
Reduce[
 {
  rho == r (1 + (Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[1/(q - 1)])/((1 - q) Gamma[1/2 ((q + 1)/(q - 1))]) b0/r + (1 + q)/(2 q) (b0/r)^(1 - q)),
  q < 0,
  b0 > 0
 },
 r
]
```

> > During evaluation of In[2]:= Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce.
> >
> > Out[2]= Reduce[{rho == 
> >        r (1 + ((1 + q) (b0/r)^(1 - q))/(2 q) + (
> >           b0 Sqrt[[Pi]]
> >             Gamma[1/(-1 + q)])/((1 - q) r Gamma[(1 + q)/(2 (-1 + q))])), 
> >       q < 0, b0 > 0}, r]

Comment: What if I specify the value for $q$ and $b0$? I tried it for $q=-2$ and $b0=1$ but I don't understand what Mathematica spit out.

Comment: It spits out `Root` objects, which are symbolic representations of the exact roots of polynomials. In this case, it gives roots of 3rd-degree polynomials, so you can use the option `Cubics -> True` in `Reduce` to expand them.

Comment: Both `Solve` and `Reduce` should give answers in terms of `Root` for integer values of `q`.  Typically, there are no solutions otherwise.